# Android Studio after migrate from 2.3.1 to 3.1.3 multiple library cause multiple Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, butterknife

When i try to migrate and update a all dependencies of my existing project its show multiple issue. i solved few of them but still getting error. I think there is issue because i had multiple library in my project and they are interdependent on each other.

Currently i stuck with butter knife dependencies not working. Some time before with one library not get import.

This is kind of big project have following Library Structure 
[image: Library Structure]

Also sharing build stature of main , core library and one of library build Structure

[image: Main]

[image: Main Build]

[image: Core build]

[image: One of Lib Build]

On core build screen shot forgot To add following dependencies structure

```
  sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/drawable-ldpi', 'src/main/res/drawable-mdpi', 'src/main/res/drawable-xdpi']
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/sqlitehelper']
    }
}
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation project(':Core')
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
```

}

Please let me know what i missing over here. Thank you in advance

Comment: What is gradle version in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` file?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @vicJordan  I check on 3 lib i have different gradle-wrapper.properties version i make them 4.4  but rest the lib doesn't show  any 'gradle-wrapper.properties' if there any way that i can manage all in single

Comment: @MuhammadUmar  currently i got error: cannot find symbol
import butterknife.InjectView; error.  If i try other way then my main project doesn't find my library files

Comment: Finally find the solution.I doing every thing correct except with butter knife. Basically my previous butter knife version is 5.1.1 but after 7+ InjectView get change to BindView.